# How can I hide IIS SMTP version number?

Tags: smtp

If I type the following command and connect to my production server (Windows 2008):

```
telnet myserver 25
```

I see the following result:

> 220 myserver Microsoft ESMTP Mail Service, Version: 7.0.xxx ready dat
>   Fri, 7 Mar 2014, 09:55 +0100

I would like to hide the version number from this reply. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;281224

Answer (score 4):

Go to `cmd.exe` then run

```
cd c:\Inetpub\Adminscripts
cscript adsutil.vbs set smtpscv/ vsi number /connectresponse “New banner here”
```

Comment: that admin script is optional. check IIS > Web Management Tools > IIS 7 Management Capability > IIS 7 Scripting Tools to see if it's enabled. Ill double check this just starting up my server.

Comment: I don't have experience with W2K8s. If you enabled IIS scripting tools it should be there. I can post the contents of adsutil.vbs or give you a link to the copy I have. Let me know how you go. You should also be able to edit the banner by following this guide as Adnan mentioned however iv never used this method personally support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;281224

Comment: The smtpsvc/1/connectresponse does not work to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer after a while and decided to help others which have the same question.

If you open the MetaBase.xml go to

1. `<IIsSmtpServer Location ="/LM/SmtpSvc/1"`
2. Add `ConnectResponse="String of Your Own Choice here"` to the step above.
3. Reboot your server if `EnableEditWhileRunning` is not enabled

The version is hidden now.